# Reload or refresh an HTML embed in an embed tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reload

I have and inside app which i need refresh time to time but not to much like for to put an insider refresh o reload timer, just wants an a button to do so and most be out because the doc it is a msql result page fully already, I will like to keep it in the embed tag if it is a way to do that !  I have try this but reload everything the thing is in the div a have a form then if i refresh everything I get

> To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier. RESEND or CANCEL

and I don't want to repeat any action.

```
<script>
function reload() {
    document.getElementById("myhtml").contentDocument=location.reload();
}</script>


<input type="button" value="Reload" onclick="reload()" >
 
<embed id="myhtml" type="text/html" src="html.php" width="100%" height="100%">

     +----------------------------------------------------+
     | +-----+ +----------------------------------------+ |
     | |     | |                                        | |
     | |     | |                                        | |
     | |     | |                                        | |
     | | div | |         embed  id="myhtml"             | |
     | |     | |                                        | |
     | |     | |                                        | |
     | |     | |                                        | |
     | |     | |                                        | |
     | +-----+ +----------------------------------------+ |
     +----------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tested whit

```
function reload() {
document.getElementById("myhtml").innerHTML=location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Try using `document.getElementById("myhtml").src="html.php"`.

Comment: ohh it works !! you should make an answer I will selected like it Thank you  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code to:

```
document.getElementById("myhtml").src="html.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load the specific div.

location.reload() is use to reload the page no to reload a div.